# ASP.NET RedirectToAction no me dirige a el controller que apunto

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Hola Amigos esoty trabajando con asp.net 6 y estoy haciendo un servicio de login como este:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model) 
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        var result = await _userAuthService.LoginAsync(model);
        if (result.StatusCode == 1)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Display","Dashboard");
        }
        else 
        {
            TempData["msg"] = result.Message;
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
        }
    }
```

LA cuestion que cuando hago `RedirectToAction("Display","Dashboard");`
me devuelve esta url

> /UserAuth/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FDashboard%2FDisplay

Parece estar concatenando el url esperado en lugar de lo esperado
me regresa a mi vista de login con la url de arriba,

Este es mi controller dashboard:

```
[Authorize]
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Display()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

A continuacion mi implementacion de servicio login

```
 public async Task<Status> LoginAsync(LoginModel loginModel)
    {
        var status = new Status();
        var userExist = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(loginModel.Username);
        if (userExist == null)
        {
            status.StatusCode = 0;
            status.Message = "Invalid username";
        }

        if (!await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(userExist, loginModel.Password))
        {
            status.StatusCode = 0;
            status.Message = "Invalid password";
        }
        var signInResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userExist, loginModel.Password, false, true);
        if (signInResult.Succeeded)
        {
            var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(userExist);
            var authClamins = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userExist.UserName)
            };
            foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
            {
                authClamins.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
            }

            status.StatusCode = 1;
            status.Message = $"Welcome user {userExist.UserName}";

        } else if (signInResult.IsLockedOut) {
            status.StatusCode = 1;
            status.Message = $"User locked out";
        }
        else {
            status.StatusCode = 1;
            status.Message = $"An error could be happening, please get in contact with service.";
        }


         
        return status;
    }
```

alguien sabria que estoy haciendo mal? Gracias

Comment: ¿Que tipo de autenticado utilizas? Como DashboardController tiene la etiqueta Authorize, entonces es muy probable que te regrese al Login si no le indicas que el usuario está autenticado. Por ejemplo en FormsAuthentication tienes que hacer SetaAuthCookie en el login de lo contrario no pasas del login

Comment: estoy usando *<form asp-action="Login" method="post">*

Comment: En el web.config que valor tiene la clave authentication dentro de system.web?

Comment: Estas Net Core. Mira HttpContext.SignInAsync quizá te ayude

Answer (score 1):

Lo que he echo en otros proyectos es regresar el POST al Javascript y desde ahí hago la redirección con:

```
 window.location.href = '/Display/Dashboard';
```

para lo del login utilizo la siguiente sintaxis, te ha de faltar algun paso.

```
//Initialize a new instance of the ClaimsIdentity with the claims and authentication scheme    
                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    //Initialize a new instance of the ClaimsPrincipal with ClaimsIdentity    
                    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                    // Set current principal
                    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
                    //SignInAsync is a Extension method for Sign in a principal for the specified scheme.    
                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, new AuthenticationProperties()
                    {
                        ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(480),
                        IsPersistent = true,
                        AllowRefresh = true,
                    });
                    return ActionResult();
```

Comment: *return RedirectToAction("Dashboard","Display");
* no puede funcionar , dado que le pasas primero el controller y luego el action, por otro lado tu otra respuesta aunque puede ser funcional no la recomiendo, dado a que te estarias brincando todo el sentido del controller y podria no ser testeable en su momento ... u.u

Comment: Ok, releyendo la pregunta, el detalle no creo que sea la redirección, me suena mas a que sea algo de la autentificación. tienes [Authorize] en Display/Dashboard, al momento de no poder autorizar, regresa al login y por eso da esa URL, porque, es la configuración para que cuando te autorices, regreses a la pagina de donde venias

Comment: Si estoy de acuerdo justo eso esta revisando, pero cuando veo mi login del metodo await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user); veo que devuelve "admin", deberia yo de agregar esa prop a algun lado???

Comment: Que tipo de autenticación estás usando?
En mi caso uso Claims y tengo que usar ese metodo para crear la cookie y se pueda autenticar bien  ` await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, new AuthenticationProperties()
                    {
                        ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(480),
                        IsPersistent = true,
                        AllowRefresh = true,
                    }); `

Comment: Si justo acabo de subir la implementacion de login, tambien uso claims

Comment: Adjunté como resuelvo los claims

Comment: una pregunta como llamo a las claims ?? entiendo que eso lo debo hacer desde mi controller, pero como obtengo las claims??

Comment: En el controlador lo llamo así:
 var company = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.System).Value;var userId = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

Comment: podrias usar mi codigo , con esta implementacion?? no lo consigo hacer bien al parecer

Comment: Solo cambia: var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(authClamins, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);, de ahí en adelante todo va igual

Answer (score 0):

antes nada mil gracias a las personas que me dedicaron su tiempo para contestar al pareces, me estaba haciendo falta utilizar

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

en el Program.cs
Espero no tener mas contratiempos de lo contrario actualizare la pregunta y su respuesta